# Verificar se Existe um Serviço

Tags: delphi-xe5, services

Segue abaixo:

```
function TfPrincipal.ServicoExiste(maquina, servico : PChar) : Boolean;
    var
      SCManHandle, Svchandle : SC_HANDLE;
      {Nome do computador onde esta localizado o serviço}
      sComputerNameEx : string;
      chrComputerName : array[0..255] of char;
      cSize           : Cardinal;
    begin
      {Verifica se nome do computador foi declarado}
      if (maquina = '') then
      begin
        {Caso não tenha sido declarado captura o nome do computador local}
        FillChar(chrComputerName, SizeOf(chrComputerName), #0);
        GetComputerName(chrComputerName, cSize);
        sComputerNameEx:=chrComputerName;
      end
      else
        sComputerNameEx := maquina;

      //ShowMessage(sComputerNameEx);

      SCManHandle := OpenSCManager(PChar(sComputerNameEx), nil, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);

      if (SCManHandle > 0) then
      begin
        Svchandle := OpenService(SCManHandle, PChar(trim(servico)), SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);

        //ShowMessage(Svchandle.ToString);
        if (Svchandle <> 0) then
        begin
          result := true;
          //ShowMessage('tem');
          CloseServiceHandle(Svchandle);
        end
        else
        begin
          result := false;
          //ShowMessage('n tem');
          CloseServiceHandle(SCManHandle);
        end;
      end;
    end;
```

Ou não funciona, ou não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar, o problema é que não retorna `true` mesmo que o nome do serviço esteja correto e instalado.

Comment: da um Break nos 2 result e roda a aplicação e onde vai parar 1º. Aparentemente esta normal!

Comment: o problema é que no segundo Handle ele retorna sempre 0;

Comment: Svchandle := OpenService(SCManHandle, PChar(trim(servico)), SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
esse ?

Comment: exatamente. esse mesmo é oque retorna 0.

Comment: Vou postar uma resposta de como eu estou usando e funcionando!

Comment: òtimo!!! muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom, estou usando em partes separadas, eu não gosto de amontoar tudo, achei essa função na net por ai faz tempo já. Acredito que seu resultado sendo sempre zero esta na forma que esta tratando os parâmetros.

```
function ServiceGetStatus(sMachine, sService: PChar): DWORD;
var
  SCManHandle, SvcHandle: SC_Handle;
  SS: TServiceStatus;
  dwStat: DWORD;
begin
  dwStat := 0;
  // Open service manager handle.
  SCManHandle := OpenSCManager(sMachine, nil, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
  if (SCManHandle > 0) then
  begin
    SvcHandle := OpenService(SCManHandle, sService, SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
    // if Service installed
    if (SvcHandle > 0) then
    begin
      // SS structure holds the service status (TServiceStatus);
      if (QueryServiceStatus(SvcHandle, SS)) then
        dwStat := ss.dwCurrentState;
      CloseServiceHandle(SvcHandle);
    end;
    CloseServiceHandle(SCManHandle);
  end;
  Result := dwStat;
end;

function ServiceRunning(sMachine, sService: PChar): Boolean;
begin
  Result := SERVICE_RUNNING = ServiceGetStatus(sMachine, sService);
end;

//Aqui eu verifico se o serviço esta rodando.
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ServiceRunning(nil, 'Servidor') then
    ShowMessage('Servidor esta Online!')
  else
    ShowMessage('Servidor não esta Online!')
end;
```